# Why 1::2::[] and [1;2] are not the same in OCaml in terms of ==?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
utop # [1;2];;
- : int list = [1; 2]
utop # 1::2::[];;
- : int list = [1; 2]
utop # 1::2::[] == [1;2];;
- : bool = false
```

Though the two expressions individually evaluated look same, why does OCaml equality function return false?

Comment: Please reformat this code.

Comment: I don't know anything on ocaml but with a online interpreter I evaluated that 1::2::[] == 1::2::[];; return false. This let me think that the == operator tests if the operands are the very same object reference, not if they are equals. I do not know the ocaml jargon, I hope it is clear what I mean.

Comment: Note that this is true for *most* languages, reference types are almost always tested for equality by pointer comparison. It would be very difficult to predict performance if the default were a deep comparison of container's contents.

Comment: It seems wrong to argue that some languages define equality through reference comparison. If you really want to know whether two things are equal, you need to make the deep comparison. Comparing references is just a way to make this faster in some cases. In OCaml, a reference comparison is defined for immutable values such that if it says `false` it gives no information. That's actually an excellent definition. And it shows why the OP's example is not paradoxical.

Comment: This is a good question, but the title should be changed to something like "Why `1::2::[]` and `[1;2]` are not the same in OCaml *in terms of* `==`?" As explained by @PatJ, the problem is with the meaning of *same*. The ultimate answer is that `==` is physical equality, but if you wrote out `1::2::[]` and `[1;2]`, you already created two different objects. Maybe some future implementation of OCaml will pool those into one, but this is not a high-priority optimization, and you could never count on it.

Comment: @antron The current implementation of the flambda opt compiler does pool those into one, but the toplevel can't (and won't) for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 19):

The `==` operator does not stand for *structural* equality but for *physical* equality. In C-like speak, it does not compare the values but the pointers. It is generally ill-advised to use it on non-mutable values (unless you are doing memoization).

To quote the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL%28==%29):

> `e1 == e2` tests for physical equality of `e1` and `e2`. On mutable types such as references, arrays, byte sequences, records with mutable fields and objects with mutable instance variables, `e1 == e2` is true if and only if physical modification of `e1` also affects `e2`. On non-mutable types, the behavior of `( == )` is implementation-dependent; however, it is guaranteed that `e1 == e2` implies `compare e1 e2 = 0`.

Now, if you try using the `=` operator which tests structural equality.

```
utop # 1::2::[] = [1;2];;
- : bool = true
```